# Populating a dropdown from the database with a selected value (hidden column)

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, dropdown

I have a control that is getting used on different pages, but on one specific page, I am having a dropdown appear that lets the user change a certain field in the database. The dropdown has two items ("Attendance Day" and "Not Attendance Day"), and I want whatever option is in the database to be loaded when the control is accessed.

Here is the top part of my Grid View:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsLookups" ID="gvValues" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="760px" OnDataBound ="GridView_DataBound">
```

Here is actual dropdown in the Grid View. On the correct page, the proper values are getting loaded from the database:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Attendance?">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList id="ddlAttendanceStatus"  AutoPostBack="True" runat ="server" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("rules") %>' >
            <asp:ListItem>Attendance Day</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Not Attendance Day</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Here is the code I'm using to currently hide the column. I'm also attempting to check to see if the item is null or not, but I haven't got that to work yet:

```
protected void GridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.LookupType == "Day Status" ? true : false)
    {
        gvValues.Columns[12].Visible = true;
        GridViewRow row = (sender as Control).Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;
        DropDownList rules = (row.FindControl("ddlAttendanceStatus") as DropDownList);
        ListItem item = rules.Items.FindByText("Attendance Day");
        if (item != null)
            rules.Items.FindByText("Attendance Day").Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Currently, the column is only appearing on the correct page, but when I go to other pages that use this control, I get an error that says:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'ddlAttendanceStatus' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value
```

I know why I'm getting this error, but I'm not sure how to work around this. Is there a way to ignore this field completely if I'm not on the correct page? Or is there a different route that I should be taking?

Please let me know if I need to post more information.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this piece of code on the aspx page: `SelectedValue='<%# Eval("rules") %>'`. In the other pages, if `rules` is not present or has a value other than `Attendance Day` or `Not Attendance Day` you'll get that error. You can solve this by setting the `SelectedValue` in the `OnRowDataBound` event.

First change the GridView on the aspx to

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsLookups" ID="gvValues" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="760px" OnDataBound="GridView_DataBound" 
    OnRowDataBound="gvValues_RowDataBound">
```

And then in code behind

```
protected void gvValues_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //find the dropdownlist with findcontrol
        DropDownList rules = e.Row.FindControl("ddlAttendanceStatus") as DropDownList;

        if (row["myColumn"].ToString() == "Day Status")
        {
            //set the correct selectedvalue
            rules.SelectedValue = "Not Attendance Day";

            //or
            rules.SelectedValue = "1";
        }
    }
}
```

Finally as an option I would recommend you use Key/Values as ListItems. This makes it easier that working with long strings.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAttendanceStatus" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Attendance Day" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Not Attendance Day" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**update**

Start by removing the `DataSourceID` from the GridView itself and move it into code behind.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = yourSource;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

And you have `AutoPostBack` set to True on the DropDownList, but do not seem to handle the PostBack. Try removing that if nothing is happening there. And for editing and updating data inside a Grid take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to get the proper values to load, but I ran into another issue. In the grid view, I need to be able to change the value of the dropdown and click an Update button to change the value in the database. However, with this solution, when I change the dropdown value, the screen refreshes and changes it back to the value stored in the database.

Comment: Updated my answer.